# Derivation of a function including singularity point.

Tags: calculus

If\begin{equation}-1<q<0,x(t)= \int_0^t (t-s)^q ds.\end{equation}
(I think)Then \begin{equation}x'(t)=0^q+q\int_0^t (t-s)^{q-1} ds.\end{equation}
Is my answer right?

Comment: Integration and differentiation don't always commute.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), for example. In particular, there are some important restrictions on the integrand.

Comment: @oen,I have look at that formula.The difficulty is that the first one \begin{equation} (t-t)^q=0^q \end{equation} with \begin{equation} q<0 \end{equation} has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the substitution $t-s=u$, then $s=t-u$ and $ds=-du$; thus your function becomes
$$
x(t)=-\int_t^0 u^q\,du=\int_0^t u^q\,du
$$
Can you go on from here?

Comment: good suggestion (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.
$$
x(t)=\int_0^t(t-s)^q\,\mathrm{d}s
$$
Then
$$
x'(t)=\overbrace{\vphantom{\int_0^t}0^q}^{1/0}+q\,\,\overbrace{\int_0^t(t-s)^{q-1}\,\mathrm{d}s}^{\text{diverges}}
$$
makes no sense. It's better to compute
$$
\begin{align}
x(t)
&=\left.\frac{-1}{q+1}(t-s)^{q+1}\right]_0^t\\
&=\frac{t^{q+1}}{q+1}
\end{align}
$$
and differentiate.

Or as egreg suggests, change variables before differentiating the integral:
$$
\begin{align}
x(t)
&=\int_0^t(t-s)^q\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\int_0^ts^q\,\mathrm{d}s\\
\end{align}
$$